# Snowflake SQL - create group ID for records related by any of three columns

Tags: sql, recursion, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm using Snowflake & trying to find a way to use SQL to group records together based on matches of either eid, phone, or email.  I've tried

Here is some example data.  The insert statements are broken up by how they should be grouped in the final product.  I'm trying to get sequential group_ids, but I don't really care which group gets group_id 1, 2, or 3 - just that there are 3 unique group_ids.

The 1st grouping (5 records):

- 1 & 5 match on phone
- 2,3,4,5 match on eid
- So, all 5 should have the same group_id which differs from the other groups

The 2nd grouping (3 records):

- 1 & 2 match on eid & phone
- 1,2,3 match on email
- So, all 3 should have the same group_id which differs from the other groups

The 3rd grouping (3 records):

- 1 & 2 match on eid
- 1 & 3 match on phone
- 1,2,3 match on email
- So, all 3 should have the same group_id which differs from the other groups

```
CREATE TABLE test_data
(
  uuid varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  eid INT NULL,
  phone varchar(25) NULL,
  email varchar(255) NULL,
  create_ts TIMESTAMP_NTZ(0) not null
);


INSERT INTO test_data (uuid, eid, phone, email, create_ts)
VALUES 
('abcd-1234-xyz',1,'555-555-5555','','2023-02-10 04:00:00'),
('1234-abcd-xyz',2,'111-111-1111','','2023-01-21 04:00:00'),
('9876-abcd-123',2,'222-222-2222','','2023-01-21 04:00:00'),
('wxyz-1234-123',2,'333-333-3333','','2023-01-21 04:00:00'),
('1234-wxyz-abc',2,'555-555-5555','','2023-01-21 04:00:00'),

('9876-wxyz-abc',3,'444-444-4444','a@email.com','2023-02-06 04:00:00'),
('abcd-wxyz-123',3,'444-444-4444','a@email.com','2022-11-23 04:00:00'),
('1234-abcd-abc',4,'777-777-7777','a@email.com','2022-01-19 04:00:00'),

('defg-1234-abc',5,'888-888-8888','h@email.com','2022-12-08 04:00:00'),
('1234-9876-xyz',5,'999-999-9999','h@email.com','2022-08-18 04:00:00'),
('9876-wxyz-def',6,'888-888-8888','h@email.com','2023-02-01 04:00:00');
```

I assume it'd be a recursive query that joins the anchor to the recursive on the different columns:

```
            on (td.eid = rec.eid and td.eid is not null) 
            or (td.phone = rec.phone and td.phone is not null)  
            or (td.email = rec.email and td.email is not null)
```

But, I'm struggling on how to create the new group_ids and assign them to the records which are related.

Thank you for taking the time to help!

Comment: You are looking for transitive closure in SQL.  The syntax may be a little different in Snowflake, but this article using recursive CTE to solve might help you: http://dwhoman.com/blog/sql-transitive-closure.html

Comment: If you look at the first group, say you had a record 6 that matched on 5 on Eid and also matched records 7 and 8 on phone (which is a different phone than records 1-5), would 6, 7 and 8 be part of that first group? Presumably, it depends which record you start with as to what the group would end up containing? What are the rules about which matches take precedence, what records to start with, how many levels of links there can be, etc?

Comment: If group 1 had a 6th record that matched to 5 on eid and 7 & 8 on phone, then 1-8 would be grouped together.  Wouldn't a recursive query loop through the different iterations so it wouldn't matter what record you start with, all the relations would be discovered?